# Why server getting down when i executed last reboot command in java?

Tags: java, linux, jsp, tomcat, process

I am running the below command to get last time when server was rebooted.

```
 last reboot -F | head -1 | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

in java ::

```
    String[] rebootProcess = { "/bin/sh", "-c","last reboot -F | head -1 | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'" };
    Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rebootProcess);
    reboot.waitFor();
    BufferedReader rebootInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reboot.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader rebootError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reboot.getErrorStream()));
    String result;
    while ((result = rebootInput.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(result);
    }
    while ((result = rebootError.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(result);
    }
```

to run this command i am using process Runtime and while running the jsp file i am getting below error and tomcat is getting down right away. Need help.

```
Error : 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bin/sh": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.Glaceinstancemonitor_jsp._jspService(Glaceinstancemonitor_jsp.java:231)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 33 more
05-Jan-2017 13:01:45.199 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
05-Jan-2017 13:01:45.286 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Jan-2017 13:01:45.336 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
05-Jan-2017 13:01:47.712 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp]
05-Jan-2017 13:01:48.713 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp]
05-Jan-2017 13:01:49.714 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp]
05-Jan-2017 13:01:50.697 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [GlaceCriticalCopy] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1245)
 java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1319)
 java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:106)
 java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
 java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
 java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
 java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
 java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:109)
 java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
 org.apache.jsp.jsp.Glaceinstancemonitor_jsp._jspService(Glaceinstancemonitor_jsp.java:250)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
05-Jan-2017 13:01:50.705 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
```

Comment: You're missing: a) the error b) the java code you use to invoke the command

Comment: Which error did you see?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a forward slash. `/bin/sh` instead of `bin/sh`.

Comment: I forgot to add some code now edited. @LukeBriggs no i am giving forward slash, edited question please check.

Comment: @Jagadeeswar Either your error message is not copied correctly, or you are not showing the code you used, because this error 'Cannot run program "bin/sh"' literally copies the first argument in your command array, i.e. "bin/sh"

Comment: i have added whole code please check. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: You have posted the wrong error message. It gives an error about bin/sh but you don't run it in your code. Please run the program again and give us the correct error message.

Comment: @Grunzwanzling i am using bin/sh to execute command and i have posted message which came in catalina while running the jsp page which executes the reboot command.

Comment: Your question seems to say that the server is going down when you execute this command. Do you mean you are getting a single error, or that the JVM is halting, or that the server is in fact coming to a halt (kernel panic/BSOD or OS shutdown)?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, when this command executed my tomcat is going down and i need to restart the tomcat again.

Comment: That's ... very surprising. Anything else in the logs? `IOException`s very rarely cause a JVM exit.

Comment: that's it from the log, nothing else. Is it okay to run that command! any other command is running fine except this last reboot command. I tried to google it but failed to query the problem exactly.